# min-height: 100%?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a CSS layout that has a 960px wide div, and I'd like to have it reach from the top of the page to the bottom. The obvious solution is `min-height: 100%;`, but it doesn't work. Here's my CSS:

```css
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
body {
background: #FF0000;
height: 100%;
}
html {
height: 100%;
}
#sheet {
width: 960px;
min-height: 100%;
background: #000000;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}
#sheet1 {
width: 760px;
min-height: 100%;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And from my HTML:

```
<div id="sheet">
    <div id="sheet1">

    </div>
</div>
```

It display fine when I change #sheet's `min-height` to `height`, but then it would get cut off if the content took up more than a page. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: use both min-height and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing #sheet to height:100%, not min-height 100%, and add some content inside of #sheet-1.

Answer (score 0):

Using 100% only takes effect only if there is HTML Element (text, image, or other elements) exist in it. Its height will be higher or shorter according to the length of the element. Thus min-height is used to specify only the exact number of length or height of the element. Try using pixels instead of percentage.

Comment: But pixels and percentage are different for a reason, I want it to be 100% of the browser window's height.

Comment: Try using fixed height for the outer div and height 100% for the inner one then the content will not push the outer div  down higher than what you have set otherwise use `overflow: hidden` to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

because you don't add any `float` or `clear` property ...

CSS will ignoring `min-height` and `max-height`, if the `height` property not defined,

Except if you add `display:inline-block`, but it can break your `margin:0px auto;` and i decide you to do like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
body {
 background: #FF0000;
 height: 100%;
 text-align:center;
}
body * {
 text-align:left;
}
html {
 height: 100%;
}
#sheet {
 width: 960px;
 display:inline-block; // It can make height auto
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #000000;
 margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#sheet1 {
 width: 760px;
 display:inline-block;
 min-height: 100%;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 text-align:left;
}
```

Replace your css, with my code and i think it should work...